# Aggregate on multiple date granularities in the same SELECT query

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, window-functions

I am using Redshift, I want to calculate the number of clients by different granularities of dates : Day, week, month.

I wrote this query :

```
SELECT new_client,
       COUNT(DISTINCT clientId) number_clients,
       DATE_TRUNC('day', _date) AS date_day,
       DATE_TRUNC('month', _date) AS date_month
FROM   ClientsTable
GROUP BY new_client, date_day, date_month
```

This returns the following result format :

```
new_client number_clients    date_day    date_month
   true         29          2023-06-01   2023-06-01
   false        135         2023-06-01   2023-06-01
   true         49          2023-06-02   2023-06-01
   false        151         2023-06-02   2023-06-01
   true         339         2023-06-03   2023-06-01
   false        97          2023-06-03   2023-06-01
   true         23          2023-06-04   2023-06-01
   false        10          2023-06-04   2023-06-01
   ...          ...           ...           ...
```

However in this case, if I want the value per month, I cannot sum the number of clients from each day : **Because the same client can visit on multiple days and I have to count him once in that case.**

What I would ideally like to do is have this kind of result :

```
new_client number_clients   date_day    date_month
   true         150          NULL        2023-06-01
   false        360          NULL        2023-06-01
   true         29          2023-06-01   2023-06-01
   false        135         2023-06-01   2023-06-01
   true         49          2023-06-02   2023-06-01
   false        151         2023-06-02   2023-06-01
   true         339         2023-06-03   2023-06-01
   false        97          2023-06-03   2023-06-01
   true         23          2023-06-04   2023-06-01
   false        10          2023-06-04   2023-06-01
   ...          ...           ...           ...
```

With the first row having agregated the value for all month.

I tried to use WINDOW function to do this as simply as possible

```
SELECT new_client,
       COUNT(DISTINCT clientId) OVER(partition BY  DATE_TRUNC('day', _date) )  number_clients_day
FROM   ClientsTable
```

I get the error

> [XX000] ERROR: WINDOW definition is not supported

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to do two different levels of aggregations and want the results in rows, we may need to use two queries to aggregate and then use `union` to get your result.

```
SELECT new_client,
       COUNT(DISTINCT client_Id) number_clients,
       DATE_TRUNC('day', _date)::text AS date_day,
       DATE_TRUNC('month', _date) AS date_month
FROM   ClientsTable
GROUP BY new_client, date_day, date_month
UNION ALL
SELECT new_client,
       COUNT(DISTINCT client_Id) number_clients,
       NULL as date_day,
       DATE_TRUNC('month', _date) AS date_month
FROM   ClientsTable
GROUP BY new_client, date_day, date_month
ORDER BY date_day ASC NULLS FIRST;
```

Caveat: This might not perform well if you have a large volume of data.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [rollup function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_GROUP_BY_aggregation-extensions.html#r_GROUP_BY_aggregation-extensions-rollup)

```sql
SELECT new_client,
       COUNT(DISTINCT clientId) number_clients,
       DATE_TRUNC('day', _date) AS date_day,
       DATE_TRUNC('month', _date) AS date_month
FROM   ClientsTable
GROUP BY new_client, rollup(date_month, date_day)
having date_month is not null;
```